# handling different namespaces for call-template in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am working on call-template, where the source looks like this.

Source:

```
    <Content>
         <first>
                <text>
                Text
            </text>
            <link xmlns="Some namespace">
                <AA>abcd</AA>
                <BB>hi all</BB>
            </link>
         </first>

         <second>
         <link xmlns="Some other namespace">
                <AA>abcd1</AA>
                <BB>hi all21</BB>
            </link>
         </second>

          <three>
         <link xmlns="other namespace">
                <AA>abcd2</AA>
                <BB>hi all33</BB>
            </link>
         </three>
    </Content>
```

XSLT written:

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:n1="Some namespace" xmlns:n2="Some other namespace" xmlns:n3="other namespace">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="Content">
       <xsl:call-template name="process">
         <xsl:with-param name="item" select="first/n1:link" />
    </xsl:call-template>
         <xsl:call-template name="process">
         <xsl:with-param name="item" select="second/n2:link" />
    </xsl:call-template>
         <xsl:call-template name="process">
         <xsl:with-param name="item" select="three/n3:link" />
    </xsl:call-template>


      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="process">
        <xsl:param name="item" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$item/AA" />
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting blank output.I know the reason because i didn't append the namespace prefix for it. like "n1:A" like that.

As the  is coming multiple times. I wrote a template and called where ever needed. But the name space of each link is diffrent. How to do I modify my code so that I can reuse the template "process".

Can any one help, how Do I modify the "process" template accordingly to handle  with diffrent namespace but same structure.

Thank you.

Comment: A `namespace=` attribute does not introduce an XML namespace.  It's just an attribute, so looking for it (`select=`)as a namespace in your XSL is not going to work.  As to an answer, that will have to wait until your XML is corrected.

Comment: @Jim Garrison. Sorry for the wrong input. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$item/AA" />
```

You could change the expression to this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$item/*[local-name() = 'AA'][namespace-uri()=namespace-uri($item)]" />
```

i.e. Check the name without namespace is 'AA', and that it has the same namespace as the parent element. This would mean if you had another 'AA' element within the 'link' element with a different namespace, it would not be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth pointing out that this is a poorly designed XML document. Whenever you see someone creating two namespaces N1 and N2 such that the local names in N1 are the same as the local names in N2, you should detect a design smell. They are making the XML much more difficult for people to process.

When I see this kind of input (it sometimes arises if people mistakenly change the namespace URI for version 2 of their vocabulary) I usually reckon that the best approach to processing it is to write a pipeline in which the first phase is to normalize the namespaces, so that the "real" processing logic doesn't have to deal with multiple namespaces in the way your code is doing, which always ends up looking like spaghetti.